# Vue CLI 3 App: Uncaught SyntaxError on NPM Build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli

I have a Vue.js application created using Vue CLI 3. It starts up fine when I run `npm run serve`, but I'm getting an error when I try to build it for deploying ( `npm run build` ).

The error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

I found several similar questions, and most of the suggested solutions centered around babel. Here's my `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, none of the suggested solutions worked for me. How can I get this to build correctly?

Edit:

NPM version: 5.5.1
Node version: 8.9.0
Vue CLI: v3.0.0-beta.15

The exact command to create the app was `vue create my-app`, and I chose `vue-router, vuex, sass, babel, typescript, unit-jest, e2e-nightwatch`.

Vue.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
    baseUrl: '/en-us/credit-application/v2',
    outputDir: '/dist/public',
    configureWebpack: {
        devServer: {
            disableHostCheck: true,
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            publicPath: '/en-us/credit-application/v2',
            openPage: 'en-us/credit-application/v2',
            open: true,
            historyApiFallback: true
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        ]
    }
};
```

Errors:

I'm getting two in the console.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < chunk-vendors.61f2fa0f.js:1`

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app.acdc6caf.js:1`

`chunk-vendors.js` leads to this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel=stylesheet><title>Credit Application</title><link as=style href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/css/app.847b19ee.css rel=preload><link as=style href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/css/chunk-vendors.95fb3ceb.css rel=preload><link as=script href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/js/app.acdc6caf.js rel=preload><link as=script href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/js/chunk-vendors.61f2fa0f.js rel=preload><link href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/css/chunk-vendors.95fb3ceb.css rel=stylesheet><link href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/css/app.847b19ee.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but the Credit Application doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript><div id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=/en-us/credit-application/v2/js/chunk-vendors.61f2fa0f.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/en-us/credit-application/v2/js/app.acdc6caf.js></script></body></html>
```

`app.acdc6caf.js` leads to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel=stylesheet><title>Credit Application</title><link as=style href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/css/app.847b19ee.css rel=preload><link as=style href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/css/chunk-vendors.95fb3ceb.css rel=preload><link as=script href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/js/app.acdc6caf.js rel=preload><link as=script href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/js/chunk-vendors.61f2fa0f.js rel=preload><link href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/css/chunk-vendors.95fb3ceb.css rel=stylesheet><link href=/en-us/credit-application/v2/css/app.847b19ee.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but the Credit Application doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript><div id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=/en-us/credit-application/v2/js/chunk-vendors.61f2fa0f.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/en-us/credit-application/v2/js/app.acdc6caf.js></script></body></html>
```

Comment: npm, node and vue cli 3.x package versions please

Comment: Plus the exact command you used to create the app (I suppose you juste used the default presets babel / eslint but please specify). I juste created one and it works.

Comment: Thanks - I added some more info in the post.

Comment: I changed my NPM/Node versions to match yours, I'm at the same beta. I created an app using the exact same prefixes. I don't have that issue. Seems like it's a loader problem, have you customized your webpack config with `vue.config.js` at all?

Comment: We probably did something in vue.config.js, but I don't remember the exact changes now. I posted the code above.

Comment: I don't necessarily see anything wrong there, either. Is this public code we could pull?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. =/ Private repo.

Comment: Can we see the actual strack trace and the line the error points to?

Comment: Sure - added them above. Appreciate the help.

Comment: it's a webserver configuration problem (files not pointing to assets but back to the index.html). Try to build and serve it yourself instead of serving with the dev-server. I think it'll be easier to make sense of the paths and urls if you have them laid out in front of you. Or reset the urls back to default (baseUrl, publicpath, outputDir) and change them little by little to what you want.

Comment: @ippi What do you mean by 'build and serve it myself'? I'm running `npm run build` and then starting the server with `node server.js`. The code works fine when I run `npm run serve`, which is the Vue equivalent of `npm run dev`.

Comment: I've considered your comments for some minutes now and I've come some  conclusions: 1) You probably moved from serve to build thinking the devServer runs with both, but in fact there is no devServer in build *unless you inject it in your config* (!!). 2) A lot of the configuration for the devServer does never happend when you build, and you get all those errors because of that. 3) You should make the devServer-config optional in your config and only load it if `process.env.NODE_ENV==="development"`. and 4) All your problems were in your head - move your built files to a real server. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. It turned out to be a web server configuration issue. Nothing to do with babel or the vue-cli template.

In my server.js file I had the following lines to serve my files:

```
let staticPath = path.posix.join('/en-us/credit-application/v2', 'public');
app.use(staticPath, express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'))
});
```

The first line was causing the error. I changed it to:

```
let staticPath = path.posix.join('/en-us/credit-application/v2');
```

Everything works! Many thanks to [ippi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497533/ippi) who got me pointed in the right direction.